# Get values only from imported file, not his imports in Python

Tags: python, module, python-import

I fave file foo.py:

```
from os import *
aaa = 'bbb'
bbb = 'asd'
...
yzx = 'asad'
```

unknow number of vars and unknown names of vars

And file bar.py:

```
vars = {}
execfile('foo.py', vars)
[print (var) for var in vars]
```

but bar.py prints also values from os (can be other imports too) :(
How to get only vars only from foo.py?

Tried pprint ads same result.

Comment: That's exactly (one of the reasons) why * imports are discouraged. At this point, you've dumped all of os into foo.py's namespace, so the vars _are_, as far as Python is concerned, vars on foo.py in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have name collisions, you can filter out the contents of `os`

```
import os
os_vars = set(dir(os))
[print(var) for var in vars if var not in os_vars]
```

Still... Ask yourself if you really need to use `import *`. This is highly discouraged.

Comment: I did used that to show my problem of imports, but files like foo.py ate input to my script. Script will never know what it will get till it imports.
Following your reasoning, i should filter off any possible combination of any imports... quite a lot. Instead, I just want to import file data.

Comment: So you're saying you have 0 control over what `foo.py` imports? Then I'm afraid you'll need to inspect the file and see what it imports before scanning the variables. It's not impossible, but definitely error prone

Comment: I think this whole thing is out of scope of this question... If I were you I'd open/search a question about how to inspect the imports of a python file

Comment: Exactly, I have no control over files i get. I know, that are proper formatting python files and they contain variables. I need those variables for further process

Comment: I'd be much surprised, that I can get all vars, but not vars from that file only in python. How to make it clever, is a trick i am asking for.

Comment: If the files had simple `import x` and `from x import y` then you could probably get away with simple regex matching. But other cases like `from .submodule import foo as bar` are tougher. Also need to take into account imports that are commented out and string literals that contain imports

Comment: I'm not a huge code inspection guy, so I can't help you much with that. But you should probably put this in another question

Comment: But you stick to manual editing file, even in memory, which is not nice programming approach. I want to achieve this without extra interfering in its code.

Comment: So that's the thing... **You can't do this without inspecting the code**. The python interpreter itself has no business with where each variable came from